# search specific tuples in list and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

let's say I have a list like this

```
liste=[(0,1,45), (0,2,90), (0,3,60), (1,2,50), (1,3,20), (2,3,25)]
```

and another list like this : `number_list=(0,2)`

so now, i would like to have a dictionary (or a list) in which i have for each key, the list of my tuples of liste, these tuples containing the numbers in number_list

on my exemple, what i want is:

```
d= { '0' : [(0,1,45), (0,2,90), (0,3,60)], '1' : [(1,2,50), (2,3,25)] }
```

so far i have written this :

```
d={}
for x in range(len(number_list)):
        d[format(x)]=[item for item in liste if number_list[x] in item]
print d
```

but it won't work and i can't understand why ?!

Thank you

Comment: don't you mean `'2' : ` instead of `'1' : `? or is it the index?

Comment: `it won't work` works here (although the output is a little different because `2` is also in `(0, 2, 90)`)

Comment: Seems about right, you need to more precisely describe what 'won't work' means - the difference between what actually happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Thank you guys! in fact what i wrote was working, but in my test file i mixed up a few names so it wasn't working because of that --'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> liste=[(0,1,45), (0,2,90), (0,3,60), (1,2,50), (1,3,20), (2,3,25)]
>>> number_list=(0,2)
>>> d = {str(x):[item for item in liste if x in item] for x in number_list}
>>> d
{'0': [(0, 1, 45), (0, 2, 90), (0, 3, 60)], '2': [(0, 2, 90), (1, 2, 50), (2, 3, 25)]}
```

Also -- note that the keys in a dictionary don't need to be strings. You could just use the numbers themselves as keys, which might be more natural.